# In HTML/CSS/javascript, Code not working as expected while Click and hovering a mouse on tabs within sub-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm Facing issue in HTML/CSS/Javascript to show sub-tab content data of tabs, let me describe my scenario in brief:

**Please execute Snippet code First:**

**So, What Happening Now:** When you hover a mouse on "Tabs Data" it will show you 3 tabs. then click on each tab will show you its side-tab "in bold" along with its respective text data of first row, without hovering a mouse over on side-tabs.

**Issue:** Once you start hovering a mouse on side-tabs, it start malfunctioning. It will show you its respective data, But stop showing first-row data along with its text content in other tabs as it showing on first load when you click. rest its working fine when you hover a mouse on side tab.

**What I want:** So Basically whenever I click on the tabs, first rows/column of side-tab data from the top in "bold" along with its respective content text should always be visible.

I'm may not be able to explain in a better way, **please run the Snippet code** to understand what I'm trying to say.

```js
function tabmenu(evt, tabname) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabname).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function sidemenu(evt, sidename) {
 var i, sidetabcontent, sidetablinks;
 sidetabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("sidetabcontent");
 for (i = 0; i < sidetabcontent.length; i++) {
  sidetabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 sidetablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("sidetablinks");
 for (i = 0; i < sidetablinks.length; i++) {
  sidetablinks[i].className = sidetablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
 }
 document.getElementById(sidename).style.display = "block";
 evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;  
}

.dropdown-menu {   
  font-size: 12px;   
  background-color: #ffcc00;      
  min-width: 50px;
}



/* Navigation Menu Bar */
#menu {
    height:45px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;    
}


#menu li {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;    
    margin-right:10px;
    border:none;
 top: 2px;  
}
 
#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
    
    /* Background color and gradients */     
    background: #ffffff;
    
     
    /* Rounded corners */     
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
 
#menu li > a {
    padding: 11px;
    font-size:14px;     
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none; 
 color: white;
}
 
#menu li:hover a {
    color:black;
}

/* Drop Down */
.dropdown_work_menu
 {    
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px; 
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;
    background:#ffffff;    
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
 
 .dropdown_work_menu { width: 400px;} 

#menu li:hover .dropdown_work_menu
 {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}
 

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;    
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;    
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 57px;
 padding: 0px;
 
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {     
 border-bottom: 3px solid #ffcc00;  
 
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {    
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffcc00; 
 
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;    
    margin-right: 15px;
 margin-top: 6px;
}



/* Style the sidetab */
div.sidetab {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    
    width: 26%;
 height: 180px;
    
}

/* Style the buttons inside the sidetab */
div.sidetab button {
 background-color: inherit;
    display: block;    
    color: black;    
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;    
    font-size: 17px;
 padding: 0px;
}

div.sidetab button:hover {     
 font-weight:bold; 
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.sidetab button.active {    
    font-weight:bold;
 
}

/* Style the sidetab content */
.sidetabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: none;
    width: 74%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 180px;
 display:none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Otpai - We Do!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<!-- Start Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse container-fluid" role="navigation">   
 <div id="navbar_row_2" class="row" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0px;">  
  <div class="col-lg-10 pull-left">
   <div class="navbar-collapse " >
    <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" >   
     <li><a href="#" ><b>Tabs Data</b></a>      
      <div class="dropdown_work_menu">              
       <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabmenu(event, 'tab1')" id="defaultOpen">TAB1</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabmenu(event, 'tab2')">TAB2</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabmenu(event, 'tab3')">TAB3</button>
       </div>
        
       <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">        
        <div class="sidetab">
         <button class="sidetablinks active" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st1')">Side Tab1</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st2')">Side Tab2</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st3')">Side Tab3</button>         
        </div>

        <div id="st1" class="sidetabcontent" style="display: block;">         
         <p>SIDE tab-11 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st2" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-12 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st3" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-13 content Description.</p>
        </div>
        
       </div>
        
       <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="sidetab">
         <button class="sidetablinks active" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st21')">Side Tab1</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st22')">Side Tab2</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st23')">Side Tab3</button>         
        </div>

        <div id="st21" class="sidetabcontent" style="display: block;">         
         <p>SIDE tab-21 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st22" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-22 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st23" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-23 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        
       </div>
        
       <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="sidetab">
         <button class="sidetablinks active" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st31')">Side Tab1</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st32')">Side Tab2</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st33')">Side Tab3</button>         
        </div>

        <div id="st31" class="sidetabcontent" style="display: block;">         
         <p>SIDE tab-31 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st32" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-32 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st33" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-33 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        
       </div>
        
       <script>
        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
       </script>
      </div>
     </li>

     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>


 
</nav>
<!-- End Navbar -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your active tag from the html seems to be responsible for the content showing as expected before you click on the sidetab links. So your function that handles the clicks on them seems to be responsible for not adding it back to the required element and chcnging the style. (I'd recommend not changing styles from js but only changing classes)

Comment: Also as you are using jquery why not use jquery code?

Comment: Hello Charsi, Thanks for your input!
Could you please help in editing snippet code and try whether is it working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when the sidemenu function changes the style of all sidetabcontent items to hide them, the display style is not inserted again until the mouseover event triggers the sidemenu function again.

To ensure the tab menu function displays the first item, you must set the css & class again you can add:

```
document.getElementById(tabname).children[1].style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(tabname).children[0].children[0].className += " active";
```

You will need to change the markup for the sidetablinks so they are no longer active until the user has selected a tab:

```
<button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st1')">Side Tab1</button>
```

Full code:

```js
            function tabmenu(evt, tabname) {
                var i, tabcontent, tablinks, sidetablinks, sidetabcontent;
                tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
                for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
                for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                sidetablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("sidetablinks");
                for (i = 0; i < sidetablinks.length; i++) {
                    sidetablinks[i].className = sidetablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                sidetabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("sidetabcontent");
                for (i = 0; i < sidetabcontent.length; i++) {
                    sidetabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                document.getElementById(tabname).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(tabname).children[1].style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById(tabname).children[0].children[0].className += " active";
                evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

            function sidemenu(evt, sidename) {
                var i, sidetabcontent, sidetablinks;
                sidetabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("sidetabcontent");
                for (i = 0; i < sidetabcontent.length; i++) {
                    sidetabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                sidetablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("sidetablinks");
                for (i = 0; i < sidetablinks.length; i++) {
                    sidetablinks[i].className = sidetablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                document.getElementById(sidename).style.display = "block";
                evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;  
}

.dropdown-menu {   
  font-size: 12px;   
  background-color: #ffcc00;      
  min-width: 50px;
}



/* Navigation Menu Bar */
#menu {
    height:45px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;    
}


#menu li {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;    
    margin-right:10px;
    border:none;
 top: 2px;  
}
 
#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
    
    /* Background color and gradients */     
    background: #ffffff;
    
     
    /* Rounded corners */     
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
 
#menu li > a {
    padding: 11px;
    font-size:14px;     
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none; 
 color: white;
}
 
#menu li:hover a {
    color:black;
}

/* Drop Down */
.dropdown_work_menu
 {    
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px; 
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;
    background:#ffffff;    
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
 
 .dropdown_work_menu { width: 400px;} 

#menu li:hover .dropdown_work_menu
 {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}
 

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;    
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;    
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 57px;
 padding: 0px;
 
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {     
 border-bottom: 3px solid #ffcc00;  
 
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {    
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffcc00; 
 
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;    
    margin-right: 15px;
 margin-top: 6px;
}



/* Style the sidetab */
div.sidetab {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    
    width: 26%;
 height: 180px;
    
}

/* Style the buttons inside the sidetab */
div.sidetab button {
 background-color: inherit;
    display: block;    
    color: black;    
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;    
    font-size: 17px;
 padding: 0px;
}

div.sidetab button:hover {     
 font-weight:bold; 
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.sidetab button.active {    
    font-weight:bold;
 
}

/* Style the sidetab content */
.sidetabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: none;
    width: 74%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 180px;
 display:none;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Otpai - We Do!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<!-- Start Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse container-fluid" role="navigation">   
 <div id="navbar_row_2" class="row" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0px;">  
  <div class="col-lg-10 pull-left">
   <div class="navbar-collapse " >
    <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" >   
     <li><a href="#" ><b>Tabs Data</b></a>      
      <div class="dropdown_work_menu">              
       <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabmenu(event, 'tab1')" id="defaultOpen">TAB1</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabmenu(event, 'tab2')">TAB2</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabmenu(event, 'tab3')">TAB3</button>
       </div>
        
       <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">        
        <div class="sidetab">
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st1')">Side Tab1</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st2')">Side Tab2</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st3')">Side Tab3</button>         
        </div>

        <div id="st1" class="sidetabcontent" style="display: block;">         
         <p>SIDE tab-11 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st2" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-12 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st3" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-13 content Description.</p>
        </div>
        
       </div>
        
       <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="sidetab">
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st21')">Side Tab1</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st22')">Side Tab2</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st23')">Side Tab3</button>         
        </div>

        <div id="st21" class="sidetabcontent" style="display: block;">         
         <p>SIDE tab-21 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st22" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-22 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st23" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-23 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        
       </div>
        
       <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
        <div class="sidetab">
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st31')">Side Tab1</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st32')">Side Tab2</button>
         <button class="sidetablinks" onmouseover="sidemenu(event, 'st33')">Side Tab3</button>         
        </div>

        <div id="st31" class="sidetabcontent" style="display: block;">         
         <p>SIDE tab-31 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st32" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-32 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        <div id="st33" class="sidetabcontent">         
         <p>SIDE tab-33 content Description.</p>
        </div>
         
        
       </div>
        
       <script>
        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
       </script>
      </div>
     </li>

     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>


 
</nav>
<!-- End Navbar -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Phil, I'm quite satisfied with your promptly given answer, But now there is another issue. After hovering out the mouse in some case 2times side-tab data and its corresponding text showing. 

Try this: Click on Tab1 -> left after hovering the mouse on bottom side-tab -> Now Click on Tab3 -> Then come back on Tab1.

You will see an output of hovering data 2times. I hope I describe properly. Thanks!

Comment: The first sidetabcontent item should not have style="display: block;", so only the mouse over event triggers hide / show mechanism, ill updat my post in a few hours

Comment: New changes posted, the issue was in the Javascript, please read the edit notes for a better implementation